# Can I use X5R ceramic capacitor for 100KHz resonance serial capacitor in wireless charger?

Tags: capacitor, wireless-charging

I am designing a Qi-compatible wireless charger.
The reference circuit design recommends to use X7R capacitor.
But a specific capacitance of X7R capacitor is out of stock at this time of writing. (C50 in the following picture.)
There's X5R capacitor available.

- Can I replace X7R capacitor with X5R one for 100 kHz resonance circuit with receiver coil?
- What is the benifit of X7R capacitor compared to X5R or other types in this frequency range?

[[image: coil resonance1]

Comment: Which capacitor? Please show a schematic.

Comment: @TimWilliams 
Schematics added. C50 is currently out of stock in in-China shops. If I use one from Mouser or Digi-Key, it will take 1 weeks more in PCBA process due to importing delay.

Comment: [Here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/x7r-x5r-c0g...-a-concise-guide-to-ceramic-capacitor-types/)is a good site to help you choose. Also  X5R are more voltage dependent than X7Rs. Personally I would choose C0G/NP0 for frequency determining circuits.

Comment: Yes, I read that article before posting this question. I tried to read it in detail, but it doesn't seem like giving answer for my question - why X7R over C0G/NP0 is recommended.

Comment: Price probably. And not understanding voltage dependence. Small volume ceramic capacitors have a crazy voltage dependence, except C0G/NP0.

Comment: Compare the dielectric losses of X5R against X7R and C0G and you'll probably see another reason.

Comment: That's no schematic, that's a tiny excerpt -- what is the blue line and text on the right side, is that supposed to be an IC? (Which one?) Why so many capacitors, why not just one and tie everything together? If an IC, does this follow mfg recommendations?

Comment: @TimWilliams Why so many capacitors - to get lower effective resistance and better thermal dissipation. And yes, that is the recommendation. Such recommendation is common for using ceramic resistors in power circuits.

Comment: @Andyaka
That seems like correct reason.